# How to set a float to a certain number of decimal places in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to set the earnings yield on a stock to a certain number of decimal places but whenever there is a repeating number it seems to ignore the rule. I am getting EPS and price data from yahoo and then dividing EPS by the price to get the earnings yield and then trying to set it to a max four decimal places. This works for every case except when there is a repeating number at the fourth decimal place. For example, if the calculation leads to a number like .106444444444 python will return the entire number instead of returning .1044, but if the number is something like .10452343, it will return .1045. Im not sure how to handle this situation when there is a repeating number.
    `from yahoo_finance import Share`.
    `ticker = Share("UTHR")`
    `price = ticker.get_price()`.
    `EPS = ticker.get_EPS_estimate_current_year()`.
    `earn_yield = float(EPS)/float(price) if EPS else 0`.
    `ey = float('%.4f' % float(earn_yield))*100`.

Comment: If you're dealing with financial or other data where exact calculations are important, you may want to look at using the `Decimal` module instead of machine floats.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
ey = float('%.4f' % float(earn_yield))*100
```

Try using the below:

```
ey = round(earn_yield*100, 4)
```

- Round returns number rounded to n digits precision after the decimal point.
- Moving the *100 multiplies the earn_yield before trying to round it.
- I also removed the floats as the ey variable should return a float here by default.

That should hopefully fix it for you!